# Find 1 column same other column different rows of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is the query below correct to find columns for which the HashCode is the same but PageUrl different rows?  This would mean basically collisions in my database planning.

```
select T1.PageUrl,T1.HashCode from tblPages as T1 inner join
(select PageUrl,HashCode from tblPages group by PageUrl,HashCode) as T2 on
T1.PageUrl!=T2.PageUrl and T1.HashCode=T2.HashCode
```

I am using 64 bit HashCode.

MS-SQL 2008 R2

Comment: FYI != is MySQL, <> is MS SQL

Comment: I am always using != and it always works with MSSQL. Would there be any difference ?

Comment: @Splash-X: For your information, `<>` is the standard SQL "Not Equal To" operator. It should work in all SQL products (and off course in both MySQL and SQL-Server). The `!=` is not standard but works in MySQL and [SQL-Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `CROSS JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause rather than your `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT T1.PageUrl,T1.HashCode FROM tblPages AS T1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PageUrl,HashCode FROM tblPages) AS T2
WHERE T1.PageUrl <> T2.PageUrl AND T1.HashCode = T2.HashCode
```

The reason for this is that the optimizer will give you a better query plan with the cross join. [Link to an example](http://www.sqlmag.com/forums/aft/77060).

Answer (score 1):

Pretty close, i would go with this:

```
select T1.PageUrl,T1.HashCode from tblPages as T1 
inner join (select distinct PageUrl,HashCode from tblPages) as T2 
on T1.PageUrl <> T2.PageUrl and T1.HashCode=T2.HashCode
```

Comment: How is that different than the OP's query?

Comment: His question is whether his query is right, and it is.  I suggested the distinct rather than the group by in the inner query and to use the SQL-Server <> rather than the !=